# how to display Native Xml Layout in React Js

Tags: android, xml, reactjs, react-native

i have an Activity(with XML layout) in Native code. i want to use that Activity in React Native... with the help of Native Modules i can display use that's fine. but that Activity is Over Laying the React Application(That Activity Filling The total mobile Screen)...

What i want is Use that entire Activity in React Java Script like a Tag.

i tried by [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) using View Manager but i can not understood how to use it..... Any help? thank you.....

Comment: inside createViewInstance you return inflate view, done